# Creating MS Teams site with PowerAutomate and adding owners to MS Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, microsoft-teams

I have flow in Power Automate via which we are creating a MS Teams site. While creating MS Teams site I can see the action 'Add a member to a team' and it works perfectly fine.

But I am not able to see any action with add a user as 'Owner' of the MS Teams site. I need to create a MS Teams site with multiple owners, but unable to find any option for that.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the newly added user to be an owner of the team using "Add a member to a team" action.

Set **Should the newly added user be an owner of the team** to **Yes**

[image]

**Microsoft documentation**: [Add a member to a team](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#add-a-member-to-a-team)